# Undetected Chrome Driver version 114 doesn't support Chrome version 116

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

A few days ago, Chrome version 116 was released, now when I run Selenium Undetected Chrome Driver, it throws an Exception "OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:98765 from session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114 Current browser version is 116.0.5845.111"

This is a C# .NET 6 project, with instances of both Selenium (https://www.selenium.dev) and Undetected Chrome Driver (https://github.com/emre-gon/Selenium.WebDriver.UndetectedChromeDriver), both throw the exception.

Selenium:

```
using (WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options))
{
}
```

result:

> InvalidOperationException:  This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114 Current browser version is 116.0.5845.111

I was able to resolve this with the WebDriverManager Nuget package, https://github.com/rosolko/WebDriverManager.Net

```
new WebDriverManager.DriverManager().SetUpDriver(new WebDriverManager.DriverConfigs.Impl.ChromeConfig());

using (WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options))
{
    //latest Chrome Driver is automatically downloaded, and now it works no more exception
}
```

But undetected chrome driver is still an issue.

```
//this version of Undetected Chrome Driver automatically downloads undetected_chromedriver.exe to the ChromeDrivers folder under the bin directory of the application
//Nuget: Selenium.WebDriver.UndetectedChromeDriver, https://github.com/emre-gon/Selenium.WebDriver.UndetectedChromeDriver
using (Selenium.Extensions.SlDriver webDriver = Selenium.WebDriver.UndetectedChromeDriver.UndetectedChromeDriver.Instance("ProfileName", options))
{
    webDriver.ExecuteScript("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})");
}
```

result:

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:98765 from session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114 Current browser version is 116.0.5845.111

The above WebDriverManager solution does not work here for undetected chrome driver

Next I tried a different Nuger package: Selenium.UndetectedChromeDriver, https://github.com/fysh711426/UndetectedChromeDriver

This one has an option to auto install the undetected chrome driver, but it didn't work

```
using (UndetectedChromeDriver webDriver = UndetectedChromeDriver.Create(driverExecutablePath: await new ChromeDriverInstaller().Auto(), options: new ChromeOptions()))
{
}
```

result:

> System.Exception: 'ChromeDriver version not found for Chrome version 116.0.5845'

```
//manually pointing to the fresh chrome driver downloaded by Selenium.WebDriver.UndetectedChromeDriver.UndetectedChromeDriver.Instance() gives the sane exception
using (UndetectedChromeDriver webDriver = UndetectedChromeDriver.Create(driverExecutablePath: "C:\\yadayadayada\\bin\\Debug\\net6.0\\ChromeDrivers\\undetected_chromedriver.exe", options: new ChromeOptions()))
{
}
```

result:

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:98765 from session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114 Current browser version is 116.0.5845.111

The latest version of both Undetected Chrome Driver Nuget packages are installed, and I still get the above exceptions. Although keeping Nuget packages up-to-date isn't really a valid solution for a production web scraping environment, I would need something like the WebDriverManager that can install the latest undetected Chrome driver automatically. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You just need to update ChromeDriver. The exception message is very explicit. The driver and browser version are incompatible.